# Convenient way to declare 2D (or even higher dimension) arrays with std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, stdarray

I'm about to convert a lot of old C++ code to more modern C++.

There are many raw 2D arrays in that code like:

```
Foo bar[XSIZE][YSIZE];
```

And I'm about to replace these declarations with

```
std::array<std::array<Foo, YSIZE>, XSIZE> bar;
```

This is a convenient way because the statements stay the same and the code is supposed to behave the same as with raw arrays with the additional benefit of being able to have out of bounds checks in debug builds.

But IMO the `std::array<std::array<Foo, YSIZE>>` is somewhat cumbersome and not easy to read, and with 3D arrays (although I have none) it would even be worse.

Right now I'm using this macro to make the declaration more readable:

```
#define DECLARE_2D_ARRAY(type, x, y) std::array<std::array<type, y>, x>
...
DECLARE_2D_ARRAY(Foo, XSIZE, YSIZE) bar;
```

But I feel this to be a macro hack, and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, more C++ way to do something similar.

Comment: unrelated to the desired answer, but, shouldn't YSIZE and XSIZE be reversed here? Typically Y would reflect number of rows, would it not? In fact, this confusion is generally a good enough reason for me not to name things x and y when referring to dimensions...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
template<class A>
struct std_array_helper {
  using type=A;
};

template<class A>
using array_t = typename std_array_helper<A>::type;

template<class T, std::size_t N0>
struct std_array_helper<T[N0]> {
  using type=std::array<array_t<T>, N0>;
};
```

now

```
array_t<Foo[XSIZE][YSIZE]>
```

is

```
std::array< std::array<Foo, XSIZE>, YSIZE>
```

an alternative solutions is:

```
template<class T, std::size_t...Sz>
struct array_helper {
  using type=T;
};

template<class T0, std::size_t...Ns>
using array_t = typename array_helper<T0, Ns...>::type;

template<class T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t...Ns>
struct array_helper<T, N0, Ns...>
{
  using type=std::array<array_t<T, Ns...>, N0>;
};
```

this uses the syntax:

```
array_t<Foo, XSIZE, YSIZE>
```

if you prefer it.

We can even combine the two, allowing either syntax.

```
template<class T, std::size_t...Sz>
struct array_helper {
  using type=T;
};
template<class T0, std::size_t...Ns>
using array_t = typename array_helper<T0, Ns...>::type;

template<class T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t...Ns>
  requires (!std::is_array_v<T>)
struct array_helper<T, N0, Ns...>
{
  using type = std::array<array_t<T, Ns...>, N0>;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t...Ns>
struct array_helper<T[N0], Ns...>:
  array_helper<array_t<T, Ns...>, N0>
{};
```

and now

```
array_t< Foo[XSIZE], YSIZE >
```

works.

But be careful - the order is tricky!

```
int[3][2] is an array of 3 elements of arrays of 2 elements.
```

To keep this the same we want

```
array_t<int, 3, 2>
```

to be

```
std::array< std::array< int, 2 >, 3>
```

**not**

```
std::array< std::array< int, 3 >, 2>
```

here are test cases to determine if you got the order right:

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::array<int, 3>, array_t<int, 3> > );
static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::array< std::array<int, 2>, 3>, array_t<int, 3, 2> > );
static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::array< std::array<int, 2>, 3>, array_t<int[3], 2> > );
static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::array< std::array<int, 2>, 3>, array_t<int[3][2]> > );
```

remove whichever have the wrong syntax for your chosen `array_t`.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/f4Gz1cvGh)

Now, even this might be wrong.  It feels incorrect that

```
array_t<int[3], 2>
```

doesn't have sub-arrays of size 3, yet

```
array_t<int[3][2]>
```

feels like it should also be the same array, and the layout of `int[3][2]` should agree with `array_t<int[3][2]>` and agree with `array_t<int, 3, 2>`.

Also, `array_t< array_t<int, 3>, 2>` should be the same as `array_t<int[3], 2>`.

These requirements disagree with each other.  I mean, all over the place they disagree.

Probably the simplest way to resolve this is to require only `[][][]` syntax, or don't permit mixed `[]` and `,` syntax.

Having `array_t<int[3][2]>` with the same layout as `int[3][2]` is high value.  Similarly, having `array_t< int, 3, 2 >` syntax is high value.  Probably we want `array_t<int, 3, 2>` to mean the same as `int[3][2]`?  Throw away this being equal to `array_t< array_t<int, 3>, 2>` - instead it equals `array_t<array_t<int,2>,3>`.  Finally, block `array_t<int[3], 2>` syntax as confusing.

Then, split the `array_t< T, 1,2,3,...>` from `array_t<T[1][2][3]...>` templates to minimize confusion.

Comment: I like this solution. It's pretty clever, especially as it works for any dimension.

Comment: @Jabberwocky careful - my first pass got the dimension order wrong.  Fixing now.

Comment: Just noticed it myself, thanks.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Didn't catch it until I added "unit tests".  ;)

Comment: Testing code. Not just for n00bs.

Comment: Could std::array<> be specialized to take T[N] as template argument, and adopt your solution?

Comment: @jxh What does `std::array<int[5],3>` mean?  ; specializations have to agree with the base template asto the kind of each parameter.  Also, changing base template messes with ABI on most compilers.

Comment: I assume you are asking if it should be `int[5][3]` or `int[3][5]`. The latter seems more sensible to me, but whatever `std::array` currently does with it would be fine with me. I am more asking about specializing `std::array` to deal with a single parameter, where the single parameter is an array type.

Answer (score 76):

You can use a [type alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
#include <array> 
#include <cstddef>

template <class T, std::size_t x, std::size_t y>
using Array2D = std::array<std::array<T, y>, x>;

int main() {
    Array2D<int, 5, 3> arr;
}
```

You can also generalize it like so for any dimension:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t... sizes>
struct ArrayHelper {
    using type = std::array<typename ArrayHelper<T, sizes...>::type, size>;
};

template <class T, std::size_t size>
struct ArrayHelper<T, size> {
    using type = std::array<T, size>;
};

template <class T, std::size_t... sizes>
using Array = typename ArrayHelper<T, sizes...>::type;

int main() { 
    Array<int, 5, 3, 4, 3> arr; 
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's elegant. Never heard of the type alias template construct before. The ... notation still freaks me out though.

Answer (score 8):

In C++23 you can use [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) to get a multi-dimensional *view* of a single-dimensional array. There is a [proposal for a `std::mdarray`](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2022/p1684r3.html), but that will not be in C++ until at least C++26.

An example of how `std::mdspan` can be used:

```
std::array<Foo, XSIZE * YSIZE> bar_1d;
std::mdspan bar(bar_1d.data(), XSIZE, YSIZE);
…
for (std::size_t y = 0; y != YSIZE; ++y) {
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != XSIZE; ++x) {
        std::cout << bar[x, y] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Looks like no compiler has a full mdspan implementation yet.